# C++ Inheritance and Includes

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, circular-dependency

I'm not brand new to C++, however I'm also definitely not an expert... yet :)

I'm trying to understand how inheritance works. I have a class that derives from a base class:

```
class Base {}
```

and

```
#include "Base.h"
class Derived : public Base {}
```

In my base class I'm trying to create a static method that returns a pointer to the Derived class object:

```
#include "Derived.h"
class Base {
     static Derived* getDerived();
}
```

Now I thought because this was a static member that I might be able to get away with it, but I get compile time issues complaining that the Derived class does not know what the Base object is, even though I'm including Base.h in the Derived class. I also am aware of the circular dependency, however because I'm trying to return a pointer to the object I figured the compiler wouldn't need the #include "Derived.h", but it seems that it does.

Any direction on why this is not the way to go and what I could do instead would be great appreciated!

(I currently do this in Java)

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Shouldn't the base class not need to know anything about the derived types?

Comment: I agree with @JamesAdkison here, the real question is why you would ever need to do this. Seems like a code smell to me.

Comment: I agree, this does not seem like good design. Our current use case is implementing a data model. And because it's a static method that is returning the derived class, the base class is mainly acting as a factory for generating the derived type. We could put the factory somewhere else, but from an API perspective it's very clean this way and that's the only reason we chose to implement in this manner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, for your case(just return a pointer to the object), the compiler wouldn't need the `#include "Derived.h"`, it just needs a [forward declaration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration):

```
class Derived;
class Base {
     static Derived* getDerived();
};
```

DEMO: http://ideone.com/ONUHGc

Comment: Yes a forward declaration is what we needed in this case, thank you! We are currently working on a better way to implement this rather than having a Base class return a Derived class object.

Answer (score 2):

The following code answers your question but **I don't know why you want to do it** at all.

It seems to me that the point of your *base* class is to provide an interface sufficient for your needs and as such **works without any knowledge of the derived types**.

### Base.h

```
#ifndef BASE_H
#define BASE_H

class Derived; // Forward declaration to avoid including 'Derived.h'

class Base
{
public:
    virtual ~Base() {}

    // Non-static function so that it has access to 'this'
    Derived* getDerived();
};

#endif
```

### Base.cpp

```
#include "Base.h"

#include "Derived.h"

Derived* Base::getDerived()
{
    return dynamic_cast<Derived*>(this);
}
```

### Derived.h

```
#ifndef DERIVED_H
#define DERIVED_H

#include "Base.h"

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    virtual ~Derived() override {}
};

#endif
```

### main.cpp

```
#include "Derived.h"

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    Derived d;
    Base* b = &d;

    std::cout << &d << " : " << b->getDerived() << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Absolutely agree that this is weird, but from an API perspective it offers a very clean API for the end user. We are currently looking at other ways we can possibly implement this without having a Base class return a pointer to an instance of a Derived class.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Circular references.

1. To use Class-Base, you need to know Class-Derived because it contains a static function with Class-Derived return type.
2. To use Class-Derived, you need to know Class-Base because it is derived from Class-Base